# hook-react-form validations not recognizing text?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have an employee form with first name, last name and email.  I'm prepopulating the email field based on the first name and last name.

If I tab thru the email field to the submit button, the form submits.  If I do not tab thru the email field (ie, enter first name, enter last name, and then click submit) the form does not validate, with the email field failing the `required` validation, even though it is popualted.  If i click in the email field (without modifying anything, just clicking and giving the input focus) the submit will then work.

The form is in mode `onChange`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Given the limited amount of info, I'd suggest installing the hook-form dev tool  https://www.react-hook-form.com/dev-tools/ and checking the state of each input field on whether you somehow initialized the `email` fields in the value without realizing it. Or simply log out the form state and see what you might have missed.